# Hide null values bars on Google Chart

Tags: google-visualization

I need to show, on a bar chart, this values:

```
Project     2013-01  2013-02  2013-03  2013-04  2013-05  2013-06
A            15       null     null     null     null     null
B            null     12       null     null     null     null
C            null     null     null     10       null     null
D            null     13       null     null     null     null
E            null     null     11       null     null     null
F            null     null     null     null     17       null
G            null     null     null     null     null     20
```

Currently I'm showing the projects as series, and the months in the X axis.

The problem is: each project will only have value to one month, but a month can have values from several projects, so a common bar chart, with several projects, will have a bunch of small bars, because of the blank spaces of the null values.

Is there a way to hide these null columns?

Or a better way to show this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value of a "Project" only ever appears in one month, then the way to fix the spacing issue is to set the "isStacked" option to true.

Comment: It doesn't work for me because a month can have more than one project, and the chart will not make sense...

Comment: If you chart the data as you presented it (with months as the data series instead of the axis values), it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/bKQNF/.  It's probably not the layout you want, but that's the only way to get the column spacing right.